# Split grid in UWP code behind

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I split grid? I mean like in designer with RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions? Here's my code:

```
composite = (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)roamingSettings.Values["enabledDays"];
            ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
            column.Width = new GridLength(20, GridUnitType.Star);
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
            try {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> MonthBool in composite) {
                    if ((bool)MonthBool.Value) {
                        column.Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Star);
                        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) {
            }
```

But I get error "No installed components were detected Element is already the child of another element" when it tries to add another column. What can I do? How to split grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out from the error message that I try to add same item (duh), so what I need to do is just simply create new object:

```
column = new ColumnDefinition();
```

So my code is now like this:

```
    composite = (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)roamingSettings.Values["enabledDays"];

    ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
    column.Width = new GridLength(20, GridUnitType.Star);
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);

    try {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> MonthBool in composite) {
            if ((bool)MonthBool.Value) {
                column = new ColumnDefinition();
                column.Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Star);
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) {
    }
```

Comment: could you please mark your answer as accepted to make it more clearly for people who later visit this. Thanks for understanding.